# Error on this Query :

Tags: mysql

Error on this Query :

```
INSERT INTO bio(name,bioid,1101,2201,remarks,department_id)
    VALUES('Julius Glenn Orienza', '575', 'FP', 'FP', 'Enroller', '10')
```

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Comment: If you have columns called `1101`, they need to be in backticks. (although I would encourage you to change the names)

Comment: From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html): `Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.`

Comment: Numeric column names are a really bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Use ` sign when you have column name in digit as below

```
INSERT INTO bio(name,bioid,`1101`,`2201`,remarks,department_id)
    VALUES('Julius Glenn Orienza', '575', 'FP', 'FP', 'Enroller', '10')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, its a big help :*

Comment: @JulsOrienza give Devsi +1 ;)